# How to get frame size in ID3v2.2 MP3 tags?

Tags: python, struct, id3, id3-tag, id3v2

I've got it sorted out for the ID3v2.3 tags, since there are 4 bytes, but the frame's header tag here is only a total of 3 bytes, not 4. That seems to mean that I can't use `struct.unpack` to get an `int` out of it.

For example, the tag I'm working with now is: `TT2\x00\x00\x0c\x00Torn Within` where `TT2` is the name identifier, and `\x00\x00\x0c` is the size identifier. The content of the tag is `\x00Torn Within`, which has a size of 12 bytes.

Here's the song's ID3 header as well. `'ID3\x02\x00\x00\x00\x04NP'`, where you can see that the encoding and flags are not set.

I've tried `struct.unpack('>3b', '\x00\x00\x0c')` but that only grabs each individual byte's value.

But after that, I am stuck, because unless I prepend a `\x00` to the size tag, I'm unable to continue. What do I do?

*Here's the ID3 tags docs http://id3.org/id3v2-00, and the docs for the `struct` module http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters*

**edit** found that I could do this: `int(binascii.hexlify('\x00\x00\x0c'), 16)` but I don't think that's a great solution

Comment: You can always prepend a `\x00` null byte..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought the same thing, but I wasn't sure if that'd have any sort of impact if the tag ever got really large, say if it was holding hires image or something. Do you think it wouldn't be an issue?

Comment: The 3 bytes limit the size of the field, your null-padding is not going to change that. 16777216 bytes is plenty for MP3 tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prepend a null byte (`\x00`) before unpacking:

```
>>> length = "\x00\x00\x0c"
>>> struct.unpack('>I', '\x00' + length)
(12,)
```

The null byte pads your length bytes out to 4 bytes without altering the meaning. The largest value the 3 size bytes can hold is 2<sup>24</sup> equals 16777216 bytes; adding the padding is not going to alter that limit in any way.